# Batch File: Setting Variable from second output line error with space on output "Was Unexpected at this time"

Tags: batch-file, variables, wmic

I have been fighting with this for 2 hours now. I need to set a variable from a second line output of a command. I found this code here at stackoverfglow:

```
for /f "skip=1delims=" %%a in (
'%SystemRoot%\System32\wbem\wmic.exe CSPRODUCT GET NAME'
) do set sid=%%a&goto next
```

The output for wmic.exe CSPRODUCT GET NAME is:

`Name
PowerEdge T610`

but when I run the batch file I get:

```
>set sid=PowerEdge T610
T610 was unexpected at this time.
```

I tried putting quotes everywhere. 
I'm doing this script to check if the computer is a VirtualBox o VMware machine, the idea is to set a variable with the output of that command then compare it to "VirtualBox". But physical computers have product name with spaces.

THANKS!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would offer the following method, as it will capture the full string without any potentially unwanted trailing space characters:

```batch-file
@For /F Tokens^=6Delims^=^" %%G In ('""%__AppDir__%wbem\WMIC.exe" CSProduct Get Name /Format:"MOF" 2>Nul"')Do @Set "SID=%%G"
```

Note: If you are using `Windows 7`, the use of some output formats may be broken, *as the relevant `.xsl` stylesheets are located inside a language specific subdirectory which is not read by default*. This issue can be worked around, by copying/moving or creating links to, all of the `.xsl` files one level higher, i.e. *inside the `wbem` directory*. ***(see potential alternative fix at the foot of this answer)***

---

Alternatively, you could omit the [for-loop](/questions/tagged/for-loop) completely, and instead of defining a variable, just use conditional statements:

```batch-file
@("%__AppDir__%wbem\WMIC.exe" CSProduct Where "Name Like '%%VirtualBox%%' Or Name Like '%%VMWare%%'" List Instance /Format:"List" 2>NUL|"%__AppDir__%find.exe" "__">NUL&&(Echo Virtual)||Echo Physical)&Pause
```

Note: In this example please ensure that you replace `VirtualBox` and/or `VMWare` as/if necessary. You can obviously replace the respective `Echo` commands with your chosen commands after testing.

---

Alternatively, for the actual process you need it for, based upon your comments, the following should also suffice:

```batch-file
@("%__AppDir__%wbem\WMIC.exe" ComputerSystem Where "Model Like '%%Virtual%%'" Get /Value 2>NUL|"%__AppDir__%find.exe" "=">NUL&&(Echo Virtual)||Echo Physical)&Pause
```

This should pick up a `Hyper-V` machine, *(Model:`Virtual Machine`)*, a `VMware` machine, *(`Model:VMware Virtual Platform`)*, and an `Oracle VM`, *(Model:`VirtualBox`)*.

---

Here is a modified [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file), which is intended to fix the potential `Format` issue in [windows-7](/questions/tagged/windows-7), *as mentioned in my first example above*:

```batch-file
@Echo Off
Set "XSL=MOF"
For /F "Delims==" %%G In ('"Set SID 2>NUL"')Do Set "%%G="
For /F "EOL=MDelims=" %%G In (
    '""%__AppDir__%wbem\WMIC.exe" OS Get MUILanguages,Version 2>NUL"'
)Do For /F Tokens^=2^,4-5Delims^=.^"^  %%H In ("%%G"
)Do If %%I Equ 6 If %%J Equ 1 (Call :Target "%__APPDIR__%wbem\%%H\%XSL%"
)Else Call :Target "%XSL%"
Set SID 2>NUL&&Pause
GoTo :EOF

:Target
For /F Tokens^=6Delims^=^" %%G In (
    '""%__AppDir__%wbem\WMIC.exe" CSProduct Get Name /Format:"%~1" 2>Nul"'
)Do Set "SID=%%G"
```

Line `9` is where you'd place your code, replacing mine which was added just for demonstration purposes.

Comment: Thanks for the super quick reply. 
Your command will set SID as "G" 

This is the output of batch file:
`B:\Projects\Done\Health\VirtualBox Tools Check>For /F Tokens=6Delims=" %G In ('""C:\Windows\system32\wbem\WMIC.exe" CSProduct Get Name /Format:"MOF" 2>Nul"') Do @Set "SID=G"

B:\Projects\Done\Health\VirtualBox Tools Check>echo G
G`

Comment: @DeftToneR - That command should end with `%%G` instead of `%G`.

Comment: I have fixed my typo, sorry for the inconvenience. I have also added an alternative method, which doesn't require using a [tag:for-loop], defining a variable, or messing with potential WMIC formatting issues in Windows 7.

Comment: Awesome @Compo thank you so much. I found that the parameter /Format:"MOF" will not work. 
Will work perfectly without it:
`@For /F Tokens^=6Delims^=^" %%G In ('""%__AppDir__%wbem\WMIC.exe" CSProduct Get Name 2>Nul"')Do @Set "SID=%%G"` (tested in several computers)

Comment: I'm sorry, @DeftToneR, but I cannot see how that command can work as you want. I have additionally added a possible, untested method for working around the [tag:windows-7] `/Format` issue. Please make sure before you run the line you're using, to use `@Set "SID="` to undefine any existing variable value before testing it again.

Comment: Hello @Compothank you so much for following this up. I will check the new code. The odl code worked without the format parameter for virtualbox result, but as VMware product name is VMWare7,1 (yes a comma). wont set the variable. So now I'm checking this new code. Again than you so much :)

Comment: Just to add a little more light to what I'm trying to do here: 
I'm trying to do a Batch script that I will run via an automatic software to all machines in a network, some of them are virtual, some physical. 

The idea of the script is to check if a machine is a VirtualBox machine or VMware machine or either of them. If is for example a VirtualBox will check if it has the tools installed. With your awesome help I used this
@("%__AppDir__%wbem\WMIC.exe" CSProduct Where "Name Like '%%VMWare%%'" List Instance /Format:"List" 2>NUL|"%__AppDir__%find.exe" "__">NUL&&(GOTO CHECK)||GOTO NOTVMware)

Comment: If you're not appending the `Pause` I added for to see the respective `Echo` message, you can remove the leading and closing parentheses too. You are still wrong however about your 'inexplicably working' command. Try this as a single line batch file, which is essentially the same: `@(For /F Tokens^=6Delims^=^" %%G In ('""%__AppDir__%wbem\WMIC.exe" CSProduct Get Name 2>Nul"')Do @Echo "%%G")&Pause`, and I'll guarantee that you only get a `Press any key to continue . . .` message, not a `"PowerEdge T610"` one!

Comment: I've also added an additional conditional example, which uses the Model from Win32_ComputerSystem instead. This is simply because my quick investigation revealed a common string for the three most common virtual machine types, `Hyper-V`, `VMware`, and `Oracle VM`, _(`VirtualBox`)_.